# How to prevent certificate pinning failure in an Azure Mobile App on iOS?

Tags: ios, azure, ssl, azure-mobile-services

Based on recommendations from a security firm, we hardened our iOS mobile app against man in the middle attacks by implementing certificate pinning.

This week, my app began failing, with `error: -999` failures, with the app reporting that the HTTP calls were cancelled. Subsequent investigation seems to show the problem to be that Microsoft updated their SSL certificates for `*.azurewebsites.net`.

Here's part of the old certificate I had pinned in my app:

```
Subject Name
    Common Name: *.azurewebsites.net

Issuer Name
    Country: US
    State/Province: Washington
    Locality: Redmond
    Organization: Microsoft Corporation
    Organizational Unit: Microsoft IT
--> Common Name: Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
```

Here's that same part for the new certificate I pulled tonight:

```
Subject Name
    Common Name: *.azurewebsites.net

Issuer Name
    Country: US
    State/Province: Washington
    Locality: Redmond
    Organization: Microsoft Corporation
    Organizational Unit: Microsoft IT
--> Common Name: Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
```

The `Not Valid Before` and `Not Valid After` dates are also different (newer certificate runs from 12/17/2017 thru 12/17/2019).

Fortunately, we haven't yet rolled out app out live to customers (but we're close, so this is scary). Obviously, this kind of service shut down once we have customers is completely unacceptable.

My question is: how can I avoid this issue biting me in the future?

I can think of 2 potential solutions, but I'm not sure exactly how Microsoft updates their certificates, and I can't find any information about that (my Google-fu might perhaps be lacking tonight).

- Solution 1: Learn when Microsoft will be updating their certificates and grab the new one as soon as it's released, putting it in my app ASAP.
- Solution 2: Provide my own SSL certificate that's pinned in the app.

Solution 1 seems problematic, as I can't currently find any information on when/how/why Microsoft updates these certificates, and given that it was less than 3 days from the new cert being issued before the old cert was inoperable, I just don't see this as a valid solution.

Solution 2 seems more attractive, as it would seem to place this more under my control, but I'm unclear on how I could do it. I can't issue a certificate against one of Microsoft's addresses. Do I issue it over a domain I control and set up some kind of forwarding to Microsoft's service?

Can someone give me the best, most secure way to accomplish this? I'm open to a "Solution 3", if I have missed something.